# how to add images in HSSFCell in apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, excel, spreadsheet

How to add Image in different different HSSFCell object in poi ?

I have written some code which is adding image but problem is, the cell were I added last image, That cell only showing image other than that no other cells are showing images ...

appreciate your help ...

My Code is

```
while(rs.next()){

    HSSFCell cell = getHSSFCell(sheet, rowNo, cellNo);

    cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(rs.getString("TEST_STEP_DETAILS")) );
    cell.setCellStyle(style);

    String annotate = rs.getString("ANNOTATE");

    if(annotate != null){                       
        int index = getPicIndex(wb);
        HSSFPatriarch patriarch=sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(400,10,655,200,(short)cellNo,(rowNo+1),(short)cellNo,(rowNo+1));
        anchor.setAnchorType(1);
        patriarch.createPicture(anchor, index);                                         
    }
    cellNo++;
}
```

getPicIndex METHOD :-

```
public static int getPicIndex(HSSFWorkbook wb){
    int index = -1;
    try {
        byte[] picData = null;
        File pic = new File( "C:\\pdf\\logo.jpg" );
        long length = pic.length(  );
        picData = new byte[ ( int ) length ];
        FileInputStream picIn = new FileInputStream( pic );
        picIn.read( picData );
        index = wb.addPicture( picData, HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i hope you found the solution yourself. if not:
the problem is that you create for every image a new partiarch.

`HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();`

you should create only one patriarch instance and use its createPicture method for all images.